# insert child comments of parent post vue js

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-component

i am using laravel 5.4 and vue 2.0. I need to insert comments of parent posts like facebook. **I want to pass 'post id' from parent to child template to insert comments of that parent post.**

```
<div class="post-section" v-for="(post,index) in posts">
    <div class="media-content" v-text='post.body'></div>
    <button @click="getComments(post, index)" class="btn btn-link">Comments</button>
    <div v-if='show' class="card comment" v-for='comment in post.comments'>
        <span>&nbsp; {{comment.comment}}</span>
    </div>

    <comment-input :post="post.id" @completed='addRecentComment'></comment-input>
</div>
```

//comment-input template

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent='onSubmit'>
        <div class="media-comment">
            <input @keyup.enter="submit" type="text" v-model='form.comment' class="form-control" placeholder="comment...">
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                form: new Form({comment: ''})
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                this.form
                    .post('/comments')
                    .then(post => this.$emit('completed', comment));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

thanks in advance !!

Comment: And so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: i want to pass post id from parent to child component (comment-input) to send the id thorough axios request to my controller. right now i am unable to send the post id from parent to child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing a prop using `:post="post.id"` declare a props property in your comment-input component like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['post']
        data() {
            return {
                form: new Form({comment: ''})
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                this.form
                    .post('/comments')
                    .then(post => this.$emit('completed', comment));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then you can use the prop in the component using `this.post`

I am refactoring your code a little bit so that it is easy to understand

Pass the postId as a prop named `postId` so that it is easily recognizble

```
<comment-input :postId="post.id" @completed='addRecentComment'></comment-input>
```

Then in your comment-input component declare the props propert like this

```
props: ['postId']
```

and finally your comment-input component

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent='onSubmit'>
        <div class="media-comment">
            <input type="text" v-model='comment' class="form-control" placeholder="comment...">
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['postId'],
        data() {
            return {
                comment: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                axios.post('api_url/' + this.postId, {comment: this.comment})
                    .then(response => {
                        this.$emit('completed', this.comment);
                        this.comment = ''; // reset back to empty
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

- you don't need exta `@keyup` event on input since the default behaviour of pressing enter in text input inside a form will submit you form
- you can just bind the input's `v-model` to empty comment in your data option

Comment: thanks @Vamsi Krishna .. I was missing the 'this.post' .. now working. But still i doesn't pass the post id to the controller it only pass the comment. I need to pass both data (comment and post_id) to my controller. I updated my question with controller side also.. can u please kindly check ???

Comment: @WahidSherief sry i do not know php

Comment: many many thanks brother. But it only passes the comments.. not the postID. i am not getting why?? u can check : https://unsee.cc/gorudema/